# Remote control option is not saved

Tags: nikon, remote, nikon-d7100

When I set Remote Control Mode in the SHOOTING MENU of my Nikon D7100 to "Quick-response mode" (for example), this option is reset to "OFF" after a few minutes...

Is this by design (possibly to save battery juice), or I do miss something?
I ask because if I plan a session of easel shootings, I will have to often open the menu and reset the option for remote, before any other setting...

Comment: Have you looked in the manual?  This may be inconsistent with some other settings you are doing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Ross Millikan I looked into the manual, and I don't think this is the case... The camera lets me set that value, but after a minute or so it is reset...